# Grab File Upload ASP Object Textbox Text with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have a webform that has an ASP file upload object and I want to use jQuery to grab the file they have selected and upload the file via AJAX.

However I am having problems grabbing the file name after it's been selected.

Here is the HTML/ASP Code:

```
 <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="NewPic" />
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="NewPic" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" Text="You need to pick a picture." CssClass="mandatory"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

This is what I have tried but doesn't seem to work

```
uploadText = $('input[type=file]').value;
alert('FileName: ' + uploadText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
uploadText = $(':file').val();
alert('FileName: ' + uploadText);
```

Comment: Do you know how to select the full file path?

As in C:\Docs\pic1.jpg

instead of just

pic1.jpg


Thanks

Comment: You can't.  Getting the full file path of a file on the client's machine is considered a security risk, and newer browsers will only ever return the file name.  Older versions of IE will give the full path however.

Answer (score 0):

I post this even though I'm unsure if `input[type=file]` behaves differently than `input[type=text]`.  But with `input[type=text]`, you call the `val()` function and not read a `value` member variable.